# "Survive" vs. "rescue"

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct?

> The rope **survives** the car from falling into the well.

Or

> The rope **rescues** the car from falling into the well.

Comment: Very different meanings,  which surely are easily understood by consulting a dictionary.  In fact both verbs are used rather unidiomatically. But again this will probably be made clearer having consulted a dictionary and understood the meanings of the two words

Comment: I wouldn't use either verb, especially because 1 they are both wrong 2  **prevents** is in my vocabulary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add to what @Michael Harvey has said.

Both *survives* and *rescues* are unsuitable.

Other than *prevents*, we could consider also **stops**.